# How I do click on a <div> tag inside a table?

Tags: javascript, powershell, powershell-2.0

I am new to PowerShell scripting, and I am stuck at a page where I need to click on a link which redirects me to the next page. I tried a number of combinations like `childNodes` / directly fetching it by `id`. But none of them seems to be working.

Webpage snippet:

```
<div id="id1" blablabla role="role1" aria-label="Redirect">
 <table role="role2" blabla>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td class="class1" blabla>
     <div id="id2" blabla>Redirect</div>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

My code:

```
$div = $ie.Document.getElementById("id1")
$table = $div.childNodes |? {$_.tagName -eq "table"}
$tbody = $table.childNodes |? {$_.tagName -eq "tbody"}
$tr = $tbody.childNodes |?{$_.tagName -eq "tr"}
$td = $tr.childNodes |?{$_.tagName -eq "td"}
$link = $td.childNodes |? {$_.tagName -eq "div"} |? {$_.innerText -match "Redirect"}
$link.click()
```

Code block 2:

```
$link = $ie.Document.getElementById("id2")
$link.click()
```

Both of the above code blocks throws the same error as below.

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At *path* char:1
+ $td.click()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What is "$ie"? `new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"`?

Comment: Hi Peter, 

I didn't paste the whole code. Only the part where click needs to work is here. Rest of the code works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to click a link you need to found the `href` property, it is the link, and do `Invoke-WebRequest` on that.

```
<a class="header-nav-link notification-indicator tooltipped tooltipped-s js-socket-channel js-notification-indicator" aria-label="You have unread notifications" href="/notifications" data-ga-click="Header, go to notifications, icon:unread" data-hotkey="g n" data-channel="tenant:1:notification-changed:*****">
        <span class="mail-status unread"></span>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="octicon octicon-bell" aria-hidden="true" viewBox="0 0 14 16" width="14" height="16" version="1.1"><path d="M 14 12 v 1 H 0 v -1 l 0.73 -0.58 c 0.77 -0.77 0.81 -2.55 1.19 -4.42 C 2.69 3.23 6 2 6 2 c 0 -0.55 0.45 -1 1 -1 s 1 0.45 1 1 c 0 0 3.39 1.23 4.16 5 c 0.38 1.88 0.42 3.66 1.19 4.42 l 0.66 0.58 H 14 Z m -7 4 c 1.11 0 2 -0.89 2 -2 H 5 c 0 1.11 0.89 2 2 2 Z" /></svg>
</a>
```

Here is a sample html from GitHub's notification button, youcan see the svg is wrapped in a `<a>` tag, if you want to 'click' that svg, just found the `href` property on the `<a>` tag (you can do that with `| select expand-property 'href'`)

and then do `Invoke-WebRequest` to get the content of that url

Comment: Here is the entire block of code from webpage. No href tag used.


<div id="id1" eventproxy="id_4" style="style" onscroll="scroll" onfocus="focus" onblur="blur" role="button" aria-label="Redirect">  <table role="presentation" >
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td class="button" style="style">
       <div id="id2" style="display:inline-block;box-sizing:border-box;max-width:100%;vertical-align:middle;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis">Redirect</div>
     </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

Document fully loaded when it calls that code block?

Before looking for elem, wait for load

```
while($ie.busy) {sleep 1};
```

Comment: yes, Document is fully loaded . Even tried by giving sleep 5000